# Problems with GNOME Panel applet execution

Tags: python, gnome, gnome-3

I'm developing a GNOME Panel applet for GNOME 3 (with D-Bus) in Python.

I'm having a problem with this, when I open the *Add to panel* dialog, my applet appear, but when I select it and press on *Add*, GNOME Panel never launch my executable script that contain the applet code (the file has execution permissions). When I execute the script manually, the added applets works fine.

I have currently installed the panel-applet file in `/usr/share/gnome-panel/4.0/applets` and the DBus service file in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services`.

If helps, those files are the following:

/usr/share/gnome-panel/4.0/applets/org.gnome.panel.applet.DynamicSeparatorApplet.panel-applet

```
[Applet Factory]
Id=DynamicSeparatorAppletFactory
Name=Dynamic Separator Applet Factory
Location=/usr/lib/dynamic-separator-applet/dynamic-separator-applet
Description=Dynamic Separator Applet Factory

[DynamicSeparatorApplet]
Name=Dynamic Separator
Name[es]=Separador Dinámico
Description=Create a separator with configurable size
Description[es]=Crea un separador con tamaño configurable
Icon=dynamic-separator-applet
BonoboId=OAFIID:GNOME_DynamicSeparatorApplet
```

/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.panel.applet.DynamicSeparatorAppletFactory.service

```
[D-BUS Service]
Names=org.gnome.panel.applet.DynamicSeparatorAppletFactory
Exec=/usr/lib/dynamic-separator-applet/dynamic-separator-applet
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Ohhhhh my Goood!! do you see in the service file? there is no `Names` should be `Name`, days and days trying to getting this work... I can't believe it :)

Comment: Add that text to the solution and then accept the solution.  You would not get any point, but people will know there is an answer for your question when looking the subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

In the D-Bus service file, I have `Names` key, and should be `Name`, so, the correct service file should be:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.gnome.panel.applet.DynamicSeparatorAppletFactory
Exec=/usr/lib/dynamic-separator-applet/dynamic-separator-applet
```